# Fechar windowsForm atual ao abrir o proximo

Tags: winforms

O meu form atual se chama FrmVender (O que está aberto) ao clicar em um botao dentro do FrmVender, quero que ele (FrmVender) feche e abra o form que eu chamar que no caso é FrmVendaImprimir.

```
FrmVendaImprimir frmVendaImprimir = new FrmVendaImprimir()
this.Close();
frmVendaImprimir.Show();
frmVendaImprimir.Focus();
```

Com esse código, o atual (FrmVender) fecha e o frmVendaImprimir abre, porem o frmVendaImprimir vai para trás da janela principal do meu sistema, ele não fica com o foco nele. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: (ignorando o conteúdo) deveria fazer isso no form que abre o "vender"... levando em consideração, que é uma venda e uma impressão, a impressão deve estar dentro da venda... não faz sentido fechar a tela da venda pra depois imprimi-la

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar dois comandos pra trazer pra frente:

```
 frmVendaImprimir.BringToFront();
```

Ou

```
 frmVendaImprimir.Activate();
```